# LDOMs in Solaris 11 don't work

Tags: virtualization, solaris, solaris-11

I just got a new Sun Fire T2000, installed Solaris 11 and was going to configure LDOMs. However "ldmd" can't be started and in turn ldm doesn't work.

```
root@solaris11:~# ldm
Failed to connect to logical domain manager: Connection refused

root@solaris11:~# svcadm enable svc:/ldoms/ldmd:default

root@solaris11:~# tail /var/svc/log/ldoms-ldmd\:default.log 
[ May 28 12:56:22 Enabled. ]
[ May 28 12:56:22 Executing start method ("/opt/SUNWldm/bin/ldmd_start"). ]
Disabling service because this domain is not a control domain
[ May 28 12:56:22 Method "start" exited with status 0. ]
[ May 28 12:56:22 Stopping because service disabled. ]
[ May 28 12:56:22 Executing stop method (:kill). ]
```

Why is this not a control domain? There is no other domain on the box (as far as I can tell).

I have upgraded the firmware to the latest 6.7.12, booted with reset_nvram, nothing helped ...

```
sc> showhost
Sun-Fire-T2000 System Firmware 6.7.12  2011/07/06 20:03

Host flash versions:
   OBP 4.30.4.d 2011/07/06 14:29
   Hypervisor 1.7.3.c 2010/07/09 15:14
   POST 4.30.4.b 2010/07/09 14:24
```

What else should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S11 contains LDoms 2.1 which is not supported on T1 hardware (the last version supported on T1 is LDoms 1.2 - see [1]). In this specific case we suggest you remove the IPS version of the LDoms manager, then download and install the SVR4 package for LDoms 1.2 (in general, on all other platforms, it's better to install the IPS package on S11 as you get dependency checking and it's much easier to upgrade).

```
pkg uninstall ldomsmanager
pkgadd SUNWldm
svcadm restart ldmd
```

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23120_01/html/821-2856/gentextid-295.html#ldomssupportedplatforms

Answer (score 1):

What version of LDOM software did you install.

```
# pkg info ldomsmanager
T2000 support only version 1.2 (or is 1.3 ?) but absolutely not versions 2.0/2.1 or 2.2
```